# AFNetworking + download file OR JSON response + setDownloadProgressBlock

Tags: json, file, download, afnetworking

I have a problem to download a file or manage an error in some cases (JSON)

The download works very fine. The problem is the server can send a 404 or 200 (with JSON) in a few cases when the user requests the download.

How to handle the JSON in this case? When we send the request we don't know if we will receive JSON error (with a 200 status oR 404) or the zipped file...

I don't see how responseObject can help me.

Here is my code:

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
  operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:zipPath append:NO];

  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
  {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded zip file to %@", zipPath);

    // is-it impossible to handle a JSON response here ?
    // responseObject can help me ? don't think !

    // do what I have to do after the download is complete
  } 
  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
  {
    // 404
    // is-it impossible to handle a JSON response here ?
    if ([error code] == -1011)
    {

    }
  }];

  [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    float progress = ((float)((int)totalBytesWritten) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToWrite));
    self.progressView.progress = progress;
  }];  
  [operation start];
```

Does I need to make a AFJSOnRequestOperation ? But in this case, how to receive the downloaded file that is not JSON ?
Thanks for helping.

EDIT: as I wroted in my comments, I can get and catch the responseData in success block ONLY if I comment the line:

```
 operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:zipPath append:NO];
```

It's logical, I suppose the response goes into outputStream instead of success block. Is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The server should signal the MIME type in the header `Content-Type`.
If it doesn't you need to detect the data type yourself.

This line ensures to get all responses with statuscode 200-499 in the success block:

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(300, 200)]];
```

In the success block you need to identify the type of response:

```
id jsonObject = AFJSONDecode(operation.responseData, NULL);
if (jsonObject) {
   // handle JSON
} else {
  // handle zip file 
}
```

You can also inspect `operation.response.statusCode` and  `operation.response.MIMEType` beforehand.

Comment: Hello phix23. The problem is operation.responseData seems to be nil when I got the JSON response instead of the file. And id jsonObject = AFJSONDecode(operation.responseData, NULL); doesn't work (inplicit declaration of function AFJSONDecode is invalid in C99)

Comment: you need to use AFHTTPRequestOperation, not AFJSONRequestOperation. For AFJSONDecode you must import AFJSONUtilities.h

Comment: More info. I can get the 200 status code, and the application/json
mineType... but responseData is null. Or can see the JSON in my browser.

Comment: OK for AFJSONDecode... but responseData is nil. :( I don't know why, the data is in my browser... (I used AFHTTPRequestOperation not AFJSONRequestOperation as you said).

Comment: responseString can be nil when the encoding doesn't match, but I have no idea why responseData is nil

Comment: I confirm that responseString and responseData are both nil. I don't know why.

Comment: phix23, I understood why I have not the response data. It's because I used the ouputStream... `operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:zipPath append:NO];` If I comment it, I have the responseData... Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: In that case you must open the written file and read the first bytes to detect if it is JSON or zip. In case you find a JSON format (starting with `[`or `{`) read the whole file.

Comment: @phix23 i got the same problem..i am trying to fetch string from my response string but it always null

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with AFJSOnRequestOperation, in .m I simply put the outputStream beneath the init:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[[self alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest] autorelease];

requestOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[FullyLoaded filePathForResourceAtURL:urlRequest.URL.absoluteString] append:NO];
```

And the same happens, responseData is nil unless commenting the outputStream line, so it's not HTTPRequest or JSOnRequest issue. The way I use to get around is to JSON sequence the object from the responseData and write it to file, rather than directly outputstream the request.

Comment: I have found the same problem when using outputStream JSON files are ignored

Comment: Some say it make sense that outputStream path will nil the responseData, since in this case, what the developer need is a file, rather than the data (which is already stored in file). But there are always some cases when we need both...

Answer (score 0):

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer =    [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/octet-stream"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:url   parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if (responseObject) {

    }
    else{

        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    }];

[operation start];
```

// manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/octet-stream"]; : can vary based on what you expect